# Android NavigationView drawer set minimum drag amount to open

Tags: android-layout, navigation-drawer, android-navigationview, android-drawer

How do you make the Drawer to auto-open (instead of back auto-close) when you drag it even with a little amount? Like maybe 10% of the screen width for example, then we release our finger and the drawer will be opened. How do we can achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the following is what you want to achieve.
But you can try this.
("mDrawerLayout" is your DrawerLayout.  "mNavigationView" is your NavigationView.)

```
    mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(new DrawerLayout.DrawerListener() {
        boolean isOpen=false;
        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(@NonNull View drawerView, float slideOffset) {

            if(slideOffset>0 && !isOpen){
                mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(mNavigationView);
            }

            if(slideOffset==1){
                isOpen=true;
            }else if(slideOffset==0){
                isOpen=false;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(@NonNull View drawerView) {
            setMenuItemUnselected();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(@NonNull View drawerView) {
            setMenuItemUnselected();
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerStateChanged(int newState) {

        }
    });
```